# data bind DropDownList with OleDbDataReader from Ms access 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to data bind my drop-down list with my database MS Access 2013 (accdb file) this is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Dima\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\networklab1\\bin\\weblabdb.accdb";
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(str);
        db.Open();
        string st = "select areaName from area;";
        OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(st, db);
        OleDbDataReader read = dbc.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = read;

        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        read.Close();
        db.Close();
    }
```

and what I get is one line "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal"
what is my mistake and how to fix this!!!
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to Check for `Postback` as well as Your are missing `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Dima\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\networklab1\\bin\\weblabdb.accdb";
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(str);
        db.Open();
        string st = "select areaName from area;";
        OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(st, db);
        OleDbDataReader read = dbc.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = read;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField="areaName";       //missing this
        DropDownList1.DataValueField="areaName";        //missing this
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        read.Close();
        db.Close();

}

    }
```

Comment: @PanteleevDima upvote and marks it as answer if you think this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing DataTextField and DataValueField.Try this-

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Dima\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\networklab1\\bin\\weblabdb.accdb";
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(str);
        db.Open();
        string st = "select areaName from area;";
        OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(st, db);
        OleDbDataReader read = dbc.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = read;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField="ShownTextFieldFromDatabaseResults";;       
        DropDownList1.DataValueField="ValueFieldFromDatabaseResults";        
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        read.Close();
        db.Close();

    }
```